# django form without id=id_fieldname

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form in django:

```
class Person(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    age = forms.IntegerField()
```

When I render the form, the html output is the following:

```
<input id="id_age" name="age" type="number">
```

Is it possible to NOT include the input id?

My desired output would be:

```
<input name="age" type="number">
```

I don't want to change the id, i want the input to not have the id attribute at all.

Comment: you can set the id from `__init__` of your forms.py.

Comment: why you don't need `id` attribute, can you explain? is there any special requirement?

Comment: It is because I will have several forms on the same page, and ids are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine what difference it makes, but you can use the [`auto_id` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#configuring-form-elements-html-id-attributes-and-label-tags) when instantiating the form in your view to turn off IDs altogether.

```
form = Person(auto_id=False)
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code below:

```
class Person(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=u'First Name', 
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {"id":"set_your_id"}),
                                max_length=30)
```

Comment: I don't want to change the id, i want the input to not have the id attribute at all.